# Is "sore" the origin for "so"?

Tags: etymology

Most of us are acquainted with this line: "The shepherds were sore afraid." Recently, in reading mysteries by C.J. Sansom, set in the time of Henry the Eighth, I see his characters using phrases like "sore cold" and "sore tired," leading them to request to sit by the fire or suggesting another might offer a place to rest.  In other words, it is causal, as in "I am sore disgusted by the smell that I must leave this place."  This suggests that these were such uncomfortable times that "soreness" or addressing Maslow's basic caloric need or safety need motivated much human behavior.  It further suggests that the word "sore" might be the source of "so."  I sorely need to know if this is so.

Comment: It is an interesting observation.  I would not be surprised if some of the idiomatic uses of the two words have "crossed" over the centuries.

Answer (score 10):

According to Google Search [ [define sore](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+sore) ],

> **sore** *adverb archaic* 1. **extremely; severely.** "they were sore afraid"

This use of the word *sore* is obsolete in modern English but still familiar due to its frequent use in in the 1601 Authorized Version of the Bible, such as the passage you cite from the Christmas story, which is well known to anyone who watched the *Charlie Brown Christmas*:

> ⁸ And there were in the same country shepherds abiding in the field,
>   keeping watch over their flock by night.
>   ⁹ And, lo, the angel of the Lord came upon them,
>   and the glory of the Lord shone round about them:
>   and they were *sore* afraid.
>   (Luke 2, AV)

In modern English, we still use *sorely* in nearly the same way, as in “he will be *sorely* missed”. And in modern German, *sore* has a close cognate: *sehr*, which is often translated *very* but in the right context can mean *sorely*. For example, “Ich werde ihn *sehr* vermissen” means literally “I will *sorely* miss him”.

*Online Etymology Dictionary* derives *[sore](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=sore)* from

> Old English *sar* "painful, grievous, aching"

but *[so](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=so)* from

> Old English *swa*, *swæ* (adv., conj., pron.) "in this way"

and the two words do not have common ancestry.

Answer (score 4):

To answer the question very simply: no. ‘Sore’ is not the source of the intensifier ‘so’.

‘Sore’ was already explained in Ed’s answer; and ‘so’ is a very old word. It is one of the many words that derive from the third person pronoun stem **so-/to-* in Proto-Indo-European (i.e., about 5,000 years ago). In Old English, it was *swa*, and it is cognate with similar words in all the other Germanic languages. It is, in other words, a much older word than ‘sore’ in this intensifying usage.